# Go: how do I view the dependency graph of packages defined within a module?

Tags: go

When creating a project in Go, you use a module (created via `go mod init`) and you can break the code into packages within that module. Since these packages cannot be imported cyclically, how do I easily view the dependency graph of the packages defined within a module? I know that I can build the code and see if I have any errors, but that's not a great way to grok or teach a codebase, and a manually maintained graph would rapidly go stale.

Figured I'd see if this functionality already exists somewhere before I write a go tool.

Comment: I think you can use this, https://github.com/kisielk/godepgraph

Comment: And you can find its usage explanation here https://jogendra.dev/import-cycles-in-golang-and-how-to-deal-with-them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `godepgraph`.

Then you can find the cycle at the graph, like this

[image]

I refered this pages

(1) https://github.com/kisielk/godepgraph

(2) https://jogendra.dev/import-cycles-in-golang-and-how-to-deal-with-them